# BehaviorSubject in shared service does not return updated value to Component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 components: `TopBarComponent` and `UserDetailsComponent`. `TopBarComponent` is common to all pages, so gets loaded along with `UserDetailsComponent` also. I have added a shared service named `UserDetailsService`.

UserDetailsService.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class UserDetailsService {
  public userData = new BehaviorSubject({});

  public setUserDetails(data: any) {
    this.userData.next(data);
  }

  public getUserDetails(): Observable<any> {
    return this.userData.asObservable();
  }
}
```

I'm setting the API response data in `UserDetailsService` from `TopBarComponent`

TopBarComponent.ts

```
//setting data in Shared Service

this.userDetailsService.setUserDetails(result.data);
```

When I am subscribing to the getter method in the service, it always returning only initial value of `BehaviorSubject`.

UserDetailsComponent.ts

```
this.userDetailsService.getUserDetails().subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);    //prints '{}' always.
  },
  error => this.error(error)
);
```

While I'm getting updated value in `UserDetailsService`, I'm always getting initial value of `BehaviorSubject`.

Where I'm doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: My guess is that you provided the service in the component instead of providing it in the NgModule. So each component has its own service instance.

Comment: Yes, I've provided the service in both the components.

Comment: Ohh..I provided the service in parent module of both the components' module and it worked. Thanks @JBNizet

Comment: Hey awesome thanks for answer JB Nizet it works if we put in main app.module!

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark the service to be global.

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserDetailsService
```

This should solve the issue. If it does not then provide it in a module that imports all the components or their modules.

```js
providers: [UserDetailsService],
```